# NetBeans: How to edit jsp file-fragments in UTF-8 outside a project?

Tags: jsp, netbeans, utf-8, character-encoding, opencms

I'm trying to work with jsp "fragments" (template files) encoded in UTF-8 in NetBeans <sup>1</sup> outside any project <sup>2</sup>. Please, notice that I'm talking about "jsp fragments," that is, I *don't think* that I can add the [<%@page%>](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref11.fm7.html) directive, as this would result in duplicated encodings directives <sup>3</sup> when building the final page <sup>4</sup>.

As I have reported in NetBeans' bugzilla [Bug 212395 - Cannot edit UTF-8 JSPs fragments in Favorites (not in projects)](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=212395), I haven't found any way to do this. Does anyone have any hint?

I have already read [How do you set the encoding to utf-8 in netbeans 6.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5034891/413020), [How to change file encoding in NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4133195/413020) and [Saving JSP as UTF-8 in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4900157/413020), but the solution in all of them is based on configuring a NetBeans project that I don't have. (I open the file from the WebDAV with File -> Open File...)

The `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` option does not have any effect at all, and my locale is also ignored (as expected after reading NetBean's [Project Encoding vs. File Encoding - What are the precedence rules used in NetBeans 6.x?](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqI18nFileEncodingQueryObject)

---

Notes:

1. NetBeans IDE 7.1.2
2. The jsp files live in a mounted WebDAV filesystem
3. From the specs ([JSR-000245 JavaServer Pages 2.1 FR](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsp-2.1-fr-eval-spec-oth-JSpec/)):

   > The pageEncoding attribute can occur at most once per file (or a
   >   translation error will result), and applies only to the file in which
   >   it appears.
4. The jsp's are opencms pages that are stitched together using `<cms:include>` tags

Comment: Side note: Since you mention OpenCms and WebDav in that context, note that my experience with using WebDav and OpenCms is, that there are a few issues and that WebDav therefore isn't reliably usable imho. Or have you been using it successfully so far? See my post at http://lists.opencms.org/pipermail/opencms-dev/2011q2/035795.html

Comment: @MathiasLin Thanks for your remark. I knew from one colleague that WebDav doesn't work flawlessly (at least, not for everyone). After checking github-bugtracker and the mailing list for WebDAV issues in OpenCms 8+, I thought that it could still be worthy giving it a chance. I'm new to OpenCms and now trying to find if we could improve our current "legacy-ad-hoc" development process. I'm using WebDAV currently only for inspecting existing code and doing small changes in existing files...No problems found so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After re-reading the JSP specs (link provided before), it seems that it *is* possible to include the page directive more than once per "translation unit:"

> A translation unit (JSP source file and any files included via the
>   include directive) can contain more than one instance of the page
>   directive [...] There shall be only one occurrence of any
>   attribute/value pair defined by this directive in a given translation
>   unit, unless the values for the duplicate attributes are identical for
>   all occurrences. The `import` and `pageEncoding` attributes are exempt
>   from this rule and can appear multiple times. [...] The `pageEncoding`
>   attribute can occur at most once per file (or a translation error will
>   result), and applies only to the file in which it appears.

It seems that I can solve the problem adding the `page` directive once per file.